# Accessing to a map value every time or assign the value to a variable. How is it actually affecting memory / power consumption?

Tags: c++, esp32

I am working on a personal project using ESP32.

From Wikipedia, ESP32 has this much memory.

> Memory: 520 KiB SRAM

(coming from a system having GB over GB of storage, this sounds scary)

Here's what I am start wondering how I should program in ESP32 regarding memory / power consumption.  (I am very new to c++)

1. If I allocate an object to a global variable, the memory size is taken from the total as long as it's ON (increases permanent memory consumption), but I always have the access to the object when I need it.
2. If I, for an instance, generate the object every time I need it, it uses CPU power, so it increases the power consumption (but it uses the memory only temporary).

How do you manage this in your ESP32 programming? as the memory size and power consumption (if on a battery) are critical, or you usually don't think about it much?

Comment: The power consumption involved in allocating an object is minimal - a few instructions. This is pretty much the very last thing you'd worry about in terms of minimizing power consumption. Nobody's power management designs ever get to the point where this matters. Memory management is much more important, but due to the small amount of available RAM and potential heap fragmentation issues, it can be as important to not allocate and free memory too much. Google "esp32 heap fragmentation" for more info.

Comment: Also, although many ESP32 programmers (and particularly people using the Arduino Core) use global variables willy nilly, they're generally a poor programming practice and shouldn't be overused. At the least use static variables to avoid polluting the global namespace, but better to structure your code to avoid them when you can. You can also have local variables which consume stack space until the scope they're in exits. And some objects (particularly `String` or `std::string`) will allocate space from the heap as needed. You're right to be concerned about the small amount of RAM :)

Comment: I think this is taking about the fragmentation? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iOJ52VIvqYM